# Reset cell when date is changed

Tags: google-sheets

I'm a small business and decided to use Google Sheets to manage my business as it is a very flexible solution and it is cost-efficient. I build myself a small CRM within sheets with automation and workflows to simplify the process using apps script.

I have a date column ''next contact'' that gives me a date to contact the customer. I would like to create another column saying ''last date contacted'' and write a formula that when ''next contact'' is changed to a new contact date, register today date into the ''last date contacted''.

How could I do this?

Comment: Have you many any attempts/research so far? What did you find/come up with? What went wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to write today's date in `last date contacted` every time the corresponding row in `next contact` gets edited, only if the edited value is a valid [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If that's the case, then you could use an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to write today's date in `last date contacted` every time column `next contact` gets edited and the edited value is a date. It could be something on the following lines:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var colIndex = range.getColumn();
  var rowIndex = range.getRow();
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && rowIndex > 1 && colIndex == 2 && new Date(value) != "Invalid Date") {
    sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 3).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

- First, the function uses the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get the range that was edited.
- Then, it checks if (1) the edited sheet is the correct one (in this example, called `Sheet1`, please change accordingly), (2) the edited row is not a header, (3) the edited column is `next contact`, (4) the edited value is a valid date.
- If all these conditions are met, a today's date is written in `last date contacted`.

Please note that in this sample:

- `next contact` is in column B.
- `last date contacted` is in column C.
- Sheet is called `Sheet1`.

Please change all these according to your case.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue

I hope this is of any help.